# PayPal payments in Android using Braintree SDK

Tags: android, paypal, braintree

- I am integrating PayPal payments in my Android app. One can't use the `PayPal Android SDK` as it is deprecated. [Docs](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK)
- As per docs `Braintree Direct` is not supported in India, they suggest using
  `Express Checkout` with the `Braintree SDK` instead.
- When I click the Express Checkout link [Here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/go-live/php) they ask me to create a production account with only those supported countries excluding India (Sandbox is working fine).
- So, how can I integrate PayPal payments for my Android app in India? For testing I have created a sandbox account [Here](https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/) which is working fine, but what can be done for production?

Answer (score 1):

You can get production credentials for "Express Checkout via Braintree SDK " from any production PayPal business account, via https://www.paypal.com/api

(It will correspond to the same kind of access token you use for "Express Checkout via Braintree SDK" in sandbox mode -- from the bottom of https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications , in that case)

Comment: Step 1: go to https://www.paypal.com/api , Step 2: obtain production Braintree SDK access token, Step 3: use production access token for your live integration

Comment: @PrestonPHX You mean to say that I don't need BrainTree production account if I have  Braintree SDK access token? Am I right?

Comment: @PrestonPHX What about **merchantId**,**public key**, **private key**?

Comment: Not used for Express Checkout via Braintree

Comment: The Braintree documentation is more current and relevant in general, but if you are looking for how to specify the access token credential in your code, the archived documentation at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/braintree-integration/ may help

Comment: @PrestonPHX Where can I replace **Braintree SDK Credentials** token with below answer's token as it also uses braintree?

Comment: The below answer uses gateway credentials to obtain a client token.  You need to use an access token to obtain a client token.